# Generic vs Interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, strategy-pattern

What is the difference between those two methods which returnes the same values?

Interface:

```
public interface Animal {
    boolean checkNull();
}
```

Main:

```
Map<String, Animal> strategyMap = new HashMap<>();

public static boolean checkIfObjectIsNull(Animal animal, Map<String, Animal> strategyMap){
    return strategyMap.get(animal.getClass().getSimpleName()).checkNull();
}

public static <T extends Animal> boolean checkIfObjectIsNullGeneric(T animal, Map<String, Animal> strategyMap) {
    return strategyMap.get(animal.getClass().getSimpleName()).checkNull();
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Strategy pattern.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use generic here. Usually generic methods are useful if two parameters expect same type (or somehow related types), or when return type should be same as type of one of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these two methods. Java will treat `T` as `Animal`. You can make those two methods have the same name. When you call one of them you will find that those two methods will conflict with each other.

Comment: "Java will treat T as Animal": no, not really. It will treat T as some unknown type extending Animal.

Comment: So basically in this example purpose of using those two methods comes from the concept which I would figure out? What I mean is that it depends on personal fantasy whereas two solutions don’t  create any big troubles during ex compilation?

Comment: @Jan Testowy In your example generic offers no benefit compared to your first implementation. Choose the one you like.

Comment: @Henry Those two methods are same after type erasure.

Comment: @zhh this is true, but the compiler works on Java before type erasure. For example, you cannot assign an object of type `Animal` to a variable of type `T`.